# NSLayoutConstraint constant standard value from code

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

In a storyboard you can set a constraint's `constant` property to be the *standard value*. Is there a way to do this from the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get standard value by using **visual format language**. If you use syntax:

```
[view][view]
```

your views' edges will be connected, but if you use this:

```
[view]-[view]
```

they will be separated by space with *standard value*. Information about this can be found in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html).